# How to determine the type of Authentication required for a REST API you have no documentation for?

Tags: python, rest, authentication, python-requests

I am interfacing with a REST API at work that I have no documentation for... because of this I have no idea how to determine the type of auth protocol it's using. Is there any possible way to determine this without any documentation from the response when sending a request lacking any authorization in the header?

Comment: What is the authentication error u are getting

Comment: @PDHide I get a response 401 (Unauthorized) but would there be anything in the response header/body that would indicate the auth type?

Comment: response body might have it depends on how the api response is implemented . Some apis returns how can the api be authenticated